# How good is the idea to place mostly entire copper layer up and down the functional layers in PCB?

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, shielding

My PCB contains PWM - driven LEDs. The specs says the internal oscillator runs at about 5.6 MHz, with currents of 30 mA per line and there are 56 lines in total. As the indicators are very large (10 cm high), it may be up till 20 cm or about tracks leading from the output of the chip to the indicator.

I am not sure how much it is a problem. But as my design fits into two PCB layers, I have an idea to place two more layers on the top and bottom of the PCB, making all tracks shielded this way. The three closely related question are:

1. Are the extra layers needed and would it make any sense. If not, probably the other two sub-questions are not required to be answered.
2. Should the extra layers be connected to the ground or left hanging?
3. Can I connect one to the ground and another to +VCC and use them to deliver power? 56 lines drawing 30 mA each means there is 1680 mA load the power bus. There are 4 pins on the LED block that are spread evenly around and should handle the load together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PWM frequency might be 5.6MHz but that doesn't mean it will actually turn ON and OFF LEDs at 5.6 MHz. Also, PWM having a PWM frequency that high in your application is also very unlikely.

Basically your PWM will get converted to average DC value and that will drive your LEDs.

Coming to your question about placing extra layers on top and bottom of PCB, they will definitely help you reducing the radiated emissions if your application requires so. But if there is no concern of RE, I don't think it is necessary.

Also, if your current requirement is not being fulfilled by your current traces that are driving LEDs or are on the edge of the specs, then you should add either extra layer or you can increase the width of the traces if the space allows on the existing layers.

If you place those extra layers, you can connect it to Ground to make best shielding out of it or you can also use it as your redundant supply path.